# how to retain dynamically added table rows and update the values in the database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

hii i am new to php and i have created a form which adds a table row dynamically wen add button is pressed i am able to save it into my database and able to retain the values when the user clicks edit but the my problem is when i press submit i.e the update button it deletes the previous records andsaves just the new added row or if i just press the update button whitout making any changes then it deletes all the values from dynamic added table i have wriiten the delete command before inserting into my database that should delete the previous record into my database and save the new one but it deletes the record and saves just the new added row can anyone help me please that would be a huge favour i am just a begginner so please frgive me if i am doing somethin wrong
here is my  code along with the javascript

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
        header("Location: unauthorize_access.php");
        }
        include("config.php");
        /*mysql_query("LOCK TABLES `makhtab` WRITE, `makhzim` WRITE, `makhalim` WRITE, `country` WRITE, `state` WRITE,  `district` WRITE, `tehsil` WRITE, `city` WRITE, `centre` WRITE, `qabiliyat` WRITE") or die(mysql_error());*/

        $newsid = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['code']); // is used for both $_GET/$_POST variables
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
             $fname     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
             $fadd1     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add1']);
             $fadd2     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add2']);
             $fadd3     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add3']);
             $fpin      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pin']);
             $ftel      = $_POST["contact"];
             $fcenter   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cmbcen']);
             $fcity     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cmbcity']);
             $fteh      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cmbteh']);
             $fdist     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cmbdist']);
             $fstate    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cmbstate']);
             $fcoun     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cmbcoun']);
             $fstu      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stu']);
             $fbatch    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['batch']);

             mysql_query("UPDATE `makhtab` SET `name`='$fname', `add1`='$fadd1', `add2`='$fadd2', `add3`='$fadd3', `pin`='$fpin', 
                         contact='$ftel', `center`='$fcenter', `city`='$fcity', `tehsil`='$fteh', `district`='$fdist', `state`='$fstate', 
                        `country`='$fcoun', students='$fstu', batch='$fbatch'  WHERE `code`='$newsid' ") or die(mysql_error());

             $num =  $_POST['rr'];
             mysql_query("DELETE FROM `makhalim` WHERE makhcode ='$newsid'")or die(mysql_error());
            print'<script type="text/javascript">';
            print"alert('alim'.$num.)";
            print'</script>';
             for($i=1;$i<$num;$i++)
             {
                $mname       = $_POST["alimname_$i"];
                $mmob        = $_POST["alimmob_$i"];
                $mqab        = $_POST["qabil_$i"];
                if(!empty($mname)){
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `makhalim`(makhcode, srno, `name`, mobile, `qabiliyat`) Values('$newsid', '$i', '$mname', '$mmob', '$mqab')") or die(mysql_error());
                 }
              }
             $hh =  $_POST['hh'];
             mysql_query("DELETE FROM makhzim WHERE makhcode ='$newsid'")or die(mysql_error());
             if($hh > 0){
                for($h=1;$h<$hh;$h++)
                {          
                    $m_name       = $_POST["zimname_$h"];
                    $m_mob        = $_POST["zimmob_$h"];

                    if(!empty($m_name)){
                       mysql_query("INSERT INTO `makhzim`(makhcode, srno, `name`, mobile) Values('$newsid', '$h', '$m_name','$m_mob')") or die(mysql_error());
                    }
                }
              }    

              /*mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES") OR die(mysql_error());*/

              print'<script type="text/javascript">';
              print "alert('Records Updated Sucessfully')";
              header("refresh: 2; makh_tab.php");
              print'</script>';

              }

              elseif($newsid)
              {

              $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `add1`, `add2`, `add3`, pin, contact, `center`, `city`, `tehsil`, `state`, `district`, `country`, students, batch FROM makhtab WHERE code='$newsid' ",$connect);
              $myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $cname      = $myrow["name"];
                    $cadd1      = $myrow["add1"];
                    $cadd2      = $myrow["add2"];
                    $cadd3      = $myrow["add3"];
                    $cpin       = $myrow["pin"];
                    $ccen       = $myrow["center"];
                    $ccity      = $myrow["city"];
                    $cteh       = $myrow["tehsil"];
                    $cstate     = $myrow["state"];
                    $cdist      = $myrow["district"];
                    $ccoun      = $myrow["country"];
                    $cstu       = $myrow["students"];
                    $cbatch     = $myrow["batch"];
    ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <title>Makhtab</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form2/view.css" media="all">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="form2/view.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="form2/calendar.js"></script>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"> 

                        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                            var jj=1;
                            function addRow()
                            {
                                //alert(jj)
                                var tbl = document.getElementById('zimtable');
                                var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                                var iteration = lastRow - 1;
                                var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

                                var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
                                var el = document.createElement('input');
                                el.type = 'text';
                                el.name = 'zimname_' + jj;
                                el.id = 'zimname_' + jj;
                                el.size = 40;
                                el.maxlength = 40;
                                firstCell.appendChild(el);

                                var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
                                var el2 = document.createElement('input');
                                el2.type = 'text';
                                el2.name = 'zimmob_' + jj;
                                el2.id = 'zimmob_' + jj;
                                el2.size = 13;
                                el2.maxlength = 13;
                                secondCell.appendChild(el2);


                                // alert(i);
                                jj++;
                                makhtab.hh.value=jj;
                                 alert(jj);
                            }
                        </script>
                        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                            var ii=1;
                            function addalRow()
                            {
                               // alert(ii);
                                var tbl = document.getElementById('alimtable');
                                var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                                var iteration = lastRow - 1;
                                var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

                                var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
                                var el = document.createElement('input');
                                el.type = 'text';
                                el.name = 'alimname_' + ii;
                                el.id = 'alimname_' + ii;
                                el.size = 40;
                                el.maxlength = 40;
                                firstCell.appendChild(el);

                                var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
                                var el2 = document.createElement('input');
                                el2.type = 'text';
                                el2.name = 'alimmob_' + ii;
                                el2.id = 'alimmob_' + ii;
                                el2.size = 13;
                                el2.maxlength = 13;
                                secondCell.appendChild(el2);

                                var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
                                var element4 = document.createElement("select");
                                element4.name ='qabil_'+ii;
                                var option1 = document.createElement("option");
                                option1.value='';
                                option1.innerHTML='';
                                element4.appendChild(option1);

                                var option2 = document.createElement("option");
                                option1.value='MUFTI';
                                option1.innerHTML='MUFTI';
                                element4.appendChild(option1);

                                var option3 = document.createElement("option");
                                option2.value='AALIM';
                                option2.innerHTML='AALIM';              
                                element4.appendChild(option2);

                                var option4 = document.createElement("option");
                                option3.value='QARI';
                                option3.innerHTML='QARI';               
                                element4.appendChild(option3);

                                var option5 = document.createElement("option");
                                option4.value='HAFIZ';
                                option4.innerHTML='HAFIZ';              
                                element4.appendChild(option3);

                                thirdCell.appendChild(element4);

                                // alert(i);
                                ii++;
                                makhtab.rr.value=ii;
                                  alert(ii);
                            }
                        </script>
                        <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
                        <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>

                        <script  type="text/javascript" src="tran/js/jq-ac-script.js"></script>
          <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
          <!--
          function isNumberKey(evt)
          {
             var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
             if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;

             return true;
          }
          //-->
    </SCRIPT>

                        </head>
                        <body id="main_body" >

                            <div id="form_container">
                                <form id="makhtab" class="appnitro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"  onsubmit="return checkForm()">
                                    <div class="form_description">
                                        <br />
                                        <h2>Makhtab Details</h2>
                                    </div>

                               <table border="0px" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">Code</label></td><td><input  name="code"  type="text" maxlength="11" size="11"  Placeholder="Please enter a code" value="<?php echo $newsid; ?>" disabled="disabled"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">Name</label></td><td><input id="name" name="name" onkeypress=""  tabindex="1"type="text" maxlength="40" size="40" value="<?php echo $cname; ?>"/></td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">Address</label></td><td><input id="add1" name="add1"  type="text" maxlength="80" size="80"  value="<?php echo $cadd1; ?>"/></td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right"></td><td><input id="add2" name="add2"  type="text" maxlength="80" size="80"  value="<?php echo $cadd2; ?>"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right"></td><td><input id="add3" name="add3"  type="text" maxlength="80" size="80"  value="<?php echo $cadd3; ?>"/></td></td>
                                            </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">Pin</label></td><td><input id="pin"  name="pin"   type="text" maxlength="10" size="10"  value="<?php echo $cpin; ?>"/></td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">Telephone</label></td><td><input id="contact"  name="contact"   type="text" maxlength="10" size="10"  value="8082034771"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                                 <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">Center</label></td><td><select name="cmbcen" class="element text medium" />
                                                 <option value="<?php echo $ccen; ?>"><?php echo $ccen; ?></option>
                                                <?php

                                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT code, `name` FROM centre") or die(mysql_error());

                                                while ($coun = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                                                    echo "<option value='$coun[name]'>$coun[name]</option>";
                                                }
                                                ?>
                            </select>
                                              </tr>
                                        <tr>

                                       <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">City</label></td><td><select id="cmbcity" name="cmbcity" class="element text medium" style="font-size:14px;">
                                                <option value="<?php echo $ccity; ?>"><?php echo $ccity; ?></option>
                                               <?php

                                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM city ") or die(mysql_error());
                                                  while ($coun = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                          echo "<option value=".$coun['name'].">".$coun['name']."</option>";
                                                  }
                                                ?></select>
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">Tehsil</label></td><td><select id="cmbteh" name="cmbteh" class="element text medium" style="font-size:14px;">
                                                <option value="<?php echo$cteh; ?>"><?php echo$cteh; ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT  `name` FROM tehsil ") or die(mysql_error());
                                                   while($coun = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                    echo "<option value=".$coun['name'].">".$coun['name']."</option>";
                                                }
                                                ?></select>
                                        </td></tr>
                                                             <tr>
                                        <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">District</label></td><td><select id="cmbdist" name="cmbdist" class="element text medium" style="font-size:14px;">
                                                <option value="<?php echo $cdist; ?>"><?php echo $cdist; ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT  `name` FROM district ") or die(mysql_error());
                                                   while($coun = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                    echo "<option value=".$coun['name'].">".$coun['name']."</option>";
                                                }
                                                ?></select>
                                        </td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">State</label></td><td><select id="cmbstate" name="cmbstate" class="element text medium" style="font-size:14px;">
                                                <option value="<?php echo $cstate; ?>"><?php echo $cstate; ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT  `name` FROM state ") or die(mysql_error());

                                                while ($coun = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                 echo "<option value=".$coun['name'].">".$coun['name']."</option>";
                                                 }
                                                ?></select>
                                        </td></tr>
                                                       <tr>
                                        <td align="right"><label class="description" for="element_1">Country</label></td><td><select id="cmbcoun" name="cmbcoun" class="element text medium" style="font-size:14px;">
                                                <option value="<?php echo $ccoun; ?>"><?php echo $ccoun; ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT  `name` FROM country ") or die(mysql_error());
                                                 while($coun = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                 echo "<option value=".$coun['name'].">".$coun['name']."</option>";a

                                                }
                                                ?></select>

                                        </td></tr>
                                  </table>          <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                                    <div class="form_description">
                                                        <h2>Zimmedar Details</h2>
                                                    </div>

                                   <table  id="zimtable" border="0px" size="100px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><strong>Zimmedar Name</strong></td>
                                                        <td><strong>Mobile</strong> </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                  <?php

                                            $zim = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `makhzim` WHERE makhcode='$newsid' ORDER BY srno")or die(mysl_error());
                                            $ctr= 0;
                                            while ($zrow = mysql_fetch_array($zim)){
                                                 $ctr++;
                                                       echo"<tr>";
                                                        echo "<td><input name='zimname_$ctr' type='text' id='zimname_$ctr' size='40' maxlength='20' value=$zrow[name] /></td>";
                                                        echo "<td><input name='zimmob_$ctr' type='text' id='zimmob_$ctr' size='13' maxlength='20' value=$zrow[mobile] /></td>";
                                                        echo "</tr>";
                                            }?>
                                       </table>
                                              <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow();" /><input name="hh" type="hidden"  id="hh" value="<?php echo $ctr; ?>"/>

                                                    <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                                    <div class="form_description">
                                                        <h2>Muallim Details</h2>
                                                        <!--<p>This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>-->
                                                    </div>

                                       <table  id="alimtable" border="0px" size="100px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><strong>Muallim Name</strong></td>
                                                        <td><strong>Mobile</strong> </td>
                                                        <td><strong>Qabiliyat</strong> </td>

                                                    </tr>
                                                    <?php 
                                                    $alim = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `makhalim` WHERE makhcode='$newsid' ORDER BY srno") or die(mysql_error());

                                                    $mctr = 0;
                                                    while($arow = mysql_fetch_array($alim)){
                                                        $ctr++;
                                                        echo "<tr>";
                                                        echo "<td><input name='alimname_$mctr' type='text' id='alimname_$mctr' size='40' value=$arow[name] maxlength='20' /></td>";
                                                        echo "<td><input name='alimmob_$mctr' type='text' id='alimmob_$mctr' size='13' maxlength='20' value=$arow[mobile] /></td>";      
                                                        echo "<td><select id='qabil' name='qabil_$mctr' class='element text large' style='font-size:14px;'/>
                                                        <option value='$arow[qabiliyat]'>$arow[qabiliyat]</option>    
                                                           <option value=''></option>    
                                                            <option value='MUFTI'>MUFTI</option>
                                                            <option value='AALIM'>AALIM</option>
                                                            <option value='QARI'>QARI</option>
                                                            <option value='HAFIZ'>HAFIZ</option>
                                                            </select></td>";
                                                        echo"</tr>";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </table>
                                                <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addalRow();" /><input name="rr" type="hidden"  id="rr" value="<?php echo $mctr; ?>" />
                                                    <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                                <table border="0px" width="85%">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                            <td width="105"><label class="description">No. of Students</label></td>
                                                            <td width="65"><input type="text" name="stu" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" size="5" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $cstu; ?>"></input></td>
                                                            <td width="105"><label class="description">No. of Batches</label></td><td width="14"><input type="text" name="batch" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" size="5" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $cbatch; ?>"></input></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                    <br /><p style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;"></p><br />
                                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="close" value="Exit"/>
                                                     </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </body>
                                                </html>

      <?php
    }
    if(isset($_POST['close'])){
        header("Location: makh_tab.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: can anyone help me out i am really stuck in a mess

Comment: Please strip out all the code that is not strictly necessary to ask your question. Too much code likely indicates that your question is not specific enough for the SO format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the problem

1. Your delete statements are targetted at field that is not a primary key

   ```
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM `makhalim` WHERE makhcode ='$newsid'") or die(mysql_error());
   AND 
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM makhzim WHERE makhcode ='$newsid'") or die(mysql_error());
   ```

Since your makhcode is not a primary key, it is maching all the records for that same code.

Comment: can you post a feedback on this ?